# ASUS F542UN laptop colors are washed out, desaturated

Tags: laptop, colors

I have a new ASUS F542UN-DM017 and the colors are washed out with the nuances just wrong and desaturated. I tried to calibrate with the tool Windows 10 comes with, but not any good. I also tried playing with Intel display settings and again, nothing good.

I have an older ASUS laptop and there the colors are fine. The difference between the two is highly visible (even bigger between the F542UN and my Samsung smartphone).

- Updated the graphics drivers, didn't work
- Contrast and brightness are at default settings
- Connecting to a TV the colors are fine
- Colors are also washed out in the BIOS

What should I do to fix it? Does anyone now what exact settings should I apply for this model or is there another solution?

Comment: right click on the desktop, Does Nvidia Control panel show up?

Comment: Yes, it does show up.

Comment: try playing around with the color settings there.

Comment: Where should I find them? I only see 3D settings.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot?

Comment: Here it is: https://drive.google.com/open?id=18ue6Zm48Kr63u6KfE424oMCfiXFDMWtP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that your laptop's built-in screen is the issue.

You can manually change color settings in Intel Graphics Control Panel to your liking.
   This is might be the best solution because it costs nothing.

Some other options:

- If your Warranty has not expired yet, You might be able to get it
  replaced.
- Replacing the LCD.